# Which episode is this scene when Lan Wangji smiles at Wei Wuxian on the roof?

Tags: mo-dao-zu-shi

I was watching this MV of *Mo Dao Zu Shi* and [the part on 5:08-5:19](https://youtu.be/Wk7CAuGI3Eo?t=5m9s) when Lan Wangji smiles at Wei Wuxian on the roof is what I haven't seen in the Anime/Donghua.

Where is this clip from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: https://v.qq.com/x/cover/k4mutekomtrdbux/c00266t1cjf.html

It's from Episode 0 —— SPECIAL WELFARE(Means it's a Cornetto advertising).